# How to do string replacements with maven-war-plugin 2.6?

Tags: maven

I can use `maven-replacer-plugin` if I am using `maven-war-plugin` version 2.0.1. The problem is, I need to upgrade to 2.6 because I am also using `overlays`, which do not work in 2.0.1. Suddenly, I am in the awkward position of being able to do only one of the two.

Is there any way to do string replacements (which is what maven-replacer-plugin, maybe using another plugin) if I am using maven-war-plugin 2.6? I am aware of `resources`, however, I cannot use that as the string replacement I am doing is not a properties file that goes into `classes` but in a directory off of `WEB-INF`. Or can I?

**UPDATE:** As per Tunaki, I tried using `filtering` in `<webresources>` but couldn't get it to work:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warName>myWar</warName>
      <overlays>
          <overlay>
              <groupId>my.group</groupId>
              <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
              <excludes>
                  <exclude>WEB-INF/some.properties</exclude>
              </excludes>
          </overlay>
      </overlays>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/my-config-dir</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

*my-config-dir* has a file *someConfig.xml* where I have a token **${prop.dir}**.  When I run `mvn clean verify -Dprop.dir=my/dir`, someConfig.xml token doesn't get replaced with my/dir

Comment: Yes, you can use `<filters>` with the `maven-war-plugin`: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html. What is the issue?

Comment: is it possible to filter without a properties file, by just specifying the variable value as a command line param (e.g. `-Drepl.with=XYZ` instead of `repl.with` being in a prop file) ?

Comment: Sure. Just make sure you add `<filtering>true</filtering>` in the `<webResource>` element. The properties file is just an addition.

Comment: please see my update

Comment: Which file did you look after creation of the WAR? You didn't specify a `targetPath` so your filtered `someConfig.xml` file will be at the root of the WAR. I tested on a sample project; worked fine (file was filtered).

Comment: But yes, the `/WEB-INF/my-config-dir/someConfig.xml` will NOT be filtered (only `/someConfig.xml` will be). That's because it was copied as part of the default copy which isn't configured to be filtered. Set a `<targetPath>` if you want to override it.

Comment: i see.  isn't there a more compact way to do this?  i just want to deploy the dir in the same place where it would be deployed if i wasn't filtering.  it seems like a lot of config for a little change

Comment: Just one more line to add `<targetPath>WEB-INF/my-config-dir</targetPath>`, inside your `<webResources><resource>`.